# Decode sed expression

Tags: sed

I would like to understand the sed part of this code:

```
/usr/local/bin/pcsensor -l60 -n | sed -e "s/^.*\$/PUTVAL downloads\/exec-environmental\/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:\0/"
```

(the input) pcsensor produces:

```
2016/09/19 22:41:31 Temperature 90.50F 32.50C
```

The code produces (output):

```
PUTVAL downloads/exec-environmental/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:32.50
```

I am hoping that understanding the sed expression will help me to knock the last digit off (so the temp is only 1 decimal place).

**Updated**: My booboo (it was late):

the -n in the first part of the command outputs this:

```
32.50
```

Which works fine in an echo/printf

```
printf "32.50 %s\n"| sed -e "s/^.*\$/PUTVAL downloads\/exec-environmental\/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:\0/"
```

Comment: I thought `\0` must be a typo, but apparently it does the same as `&` (repeats the whole match). I can't see this documented anywhere, though.

Comment: Which version of sed are you using, by the way? I'm getting different output for your input with this sed command.

Comment: I do not talk sed in anyway. It's gobbledegook to me. sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: The input and output do not match.

Comment: They were examples. The numbers are a temperature. Ive updated the example to "match". This is copy and paste from a live server. This code works. I dont understand it though.

Comment: @Frank_Zafka I am getting the entire `pcsensor` output after the `N:`.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I get the same with an echo statement. But not with the command. Damned if i know what's going on.

Comment: Does `pcsensor` print to stderr? Try piping with `|&`. (Or, if not using Bash, with `2>&1 |`)

Comment: pcsensor prints to the commandline..if that's what you're asking. I can run this from a bash prompt with no problem `pcsensor -l60 -n | sed -e "s/^.*\$/PUTVAL downloads\/exec-environmental\/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:\0/"`

Comment: The sed command substitutes the complete input with the expression that starts at `PUTVAL` and inserts it again where the `\0` is, at least for me. I don't know who you can get your output with your input. What happened to the `C` at the end? Why would `\0` expand to `32.50`? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Like I say, it was late. It is clear that most of the cutting is not being done by sed, but by the -n. Ive updated the question. Perhaps it is clear now and an answer forthcoming? ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About

```
sed -e "s/^.*\$/PUTVAL downloads\/exec-environmental\/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:\0/"
```

This is 1 sed command, namely the `s/.../.../` for "substitute". In simple terms, it does a single "search and replace" for every line that it gets to work on.

The "search" part is `^.*\$`, the "replacement" part is `PUTVAL downloads\/exec-environmental\/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:\0/`.

`^.*\$` is a simple [Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that here stands for "everything" or "the whole line". So, the `s` command will replace the whole line with

```
PUTVAL downloads\/exec-environmental\/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:\0/
```

As Benjamin W. [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582607/decode-sed-expression?noredirect=1#comment66475261_39582607) the use of `\0` is "weird". It apparently was meant as a so-called reference, so that the part we searched for is appended after the text "PUTVAL(...)val=30 N:".

I have several issues with the way this is presented, though.

- `\0` is not in the manpage of my Debian GNU Sed 4.2.2.
- Quoting the `sed` command with `"` is not needed here and makes things unnecessarily complicated and error-prone. Single quotes should be used instead.
- A `\0` anywhere in a Shell and especially in Sed could very well stand for a null character which here raises even more red flags due to the `"` quoting.
- Using `sed` just to prepend a text is "useless use of Sed".

Since you asked about `sed`, here is how I would write it:

```
sed -e 's/^.*$/PUTVAL downloads\/exec-environmental\/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:&/'
```

`&` stands for "what the search part found". In your case, the whole line.

In order to cut off the last decimal, there are many ways to achieve this. A rather simple approach assumes that the input always has 2 decimals. Then we could prepend a command that replaces the last character (`.$`) with "nothing" (`//`):

```
sed -e 's/.$//;s/^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]/PUTVAL downloads\/exec-environmental\/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:&/'
```

However, as I said, `sed` is overkill here. You could just use for instance `printf`:

```
text='PUTVAL downloads/exec-environmental/temperature-cpu interval=30 N:'
printf "%s%3.1f\n" "$text" $(/usr/local/bin/pcsensor -l60 -n)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well that's that then. And removing the extra digit didnt change anything for the other situation. Just more of me trying anything that i can think of. :)